# Making User Enter Information Into Textboxes before Submitting

Tags: ms-access, textbox, vba

I have created 5 textboxes in a form and I'm looking for some VBA code that will prompt the User to enter a value into at least one of the 5 boxes. I have figured out a code to make the user put data into a specified textbox but I'm looking to validate all five at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider 3 text boxes.  When none of them contain a value, `IsNull()` will be True for each of them.  So you could test an `If ... Then` condition to determine when they are all Null.

```vb
If IsNull(Me.Text1) And IsNull(Me.Text2) And IsNull(Me.Text3) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a value in at least one text box."
End If
```

You could use that in your form's Before Update event and set Cancel=True to cancel the update when all are Null:

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If IsNull(Me.Text1) And IsNull(Me.Text2) And IsNull(Me.Text3) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a value in at least one text box."
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

If this suggestion is useful, all you should need to do is extend it from 3 to 5 text boxes.

Comment: Awesome that worked great thank you! Do you know any code that makes submitting what the user has entered into the form not get entered into the table if the textboxes arent entered. In the code now the message boxes are showing up perfectly, but the entry is still showing in the table.

Comment: `Cancel = True` should prevent saving a modified record.  I don't understand why it's not.  If you need the same validation for new records, try the code in `Form_BeforeInsert` also.

Comment: I dont understand either even my table is not automatically updating when I press the submit button I have to go into the table and press the refresh button to show the new record that has been added from the form

Comment: We're lost in the details and I don't know what to ask in order to clarify the situation. If you upload a copy of your db to a file sharing site, I will see whether I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: Do you have a specific sharing site? And I can send you my code I have mine behind a command button

Comment: Wikisend, DropBox, Google Drive, OneDrive ... wherever is convenient for you.